# Unable to register a node on virtual machine using selenium Grid

Tags: grid, selenium-grid

I am newbie with Selenium Grid therefore any help in this regard is much appreciated.

I am using following version of selenium server:

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar
```

I've successfully manged to initialize the hub by entering this into cmd line:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub`

I have also managed to register a node on my physical machine by executing the following command line:

*java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role webdriver -hub `http://localhost:4444`/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS -port 5556*

I've verified the above by going to `http://localhost:4444`/grid/console and can see that node has successfully been registered to port 5556.

Now as next step, I am trying to register another node on Windows7 virtual machine(ip address=10.0.0.79) by running the following in cmd line:

*java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role webdriver -hub `http://10.0.0.79:4444`/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS*

unfortunately the above cmd doesn't register my request and I get the error: couldn't rgister this node : hub down or not responding

I would be grateful if someone can please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: Did you make sure whether you can ping this 10.0.0.79 machine from the win7 VM? And also, did you check whether your firewall is blocking the connection?

Comment: @ A.J - Just like to clarify that the IP address of my localhost =10.0.0.115 and IP address of the VM=10.0.079. 

As per your suggestion, I can confirm that I can successfully ping VM from my phical mac machien and vice versa. 
I have also checked that the firewallon my virtual machine (10.0.0.79) is already turned off.

Is there anything else in the way I am trying to register node on VM which could be wrong, i.e. the IP address, port number etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.0.0.79 is the IP of your node, not the Hub right? The Hub is running outside the VM (with a different IP)

In your last command you let it point to a hub on 10.0.0.79

Comment: Thanks Jochen.

So just to clarify, you're saying that when i register my node on the VM (10.0.0.79) from my hub (Physical machine- IP 10.0.0115), i should call the following command:

**java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://10.0.0.115:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS**

But surely wouldn't the above simply create another node on my physical machine (ip=10.0.0.115)?

Comment: The above command should be run in the VM and not hub. When you run this command, a node will be created in that VM and registered to the hub which is listening in 10.0.0.115

Comment: Thank you guys - I understand what i did wrong now - I've now successfully managed to register a node on my VM. Cheers